# How to prove that a logarithmic function has a unique root over a certain domain?

Tags: logarithms

How to prove that a natural logarithm function has a unique root over its domain OR over a certain given domain? For example: f(x)=xln(x)-x-1 for x>0
And how can we solve the equation of xln(x)-x-1=0?
And does the term "unique root” exclude the case of having a double root(two equal roots)?
Thnx in advance for anwering :)

Comment: On this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: How do you define "double root"?

Comment: A double root is two equal roots eg f(x)=(x+2)^2 has two equal roots x'=x''=-2 so we can say that -2 is a double root of this function

Answer (score 1):

First $f(1)=-2$.

Second, observe that $f(x)\to -1$ as $x\to0^+$. Also $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$. Since $f$ is continuous there must be a zero in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Third, $f'(x)=\ln(x)$, which is positive for $x>1$ and negative for $0<x<1$.
This means that $f$ decreases from $-1$ to $-2$ on $(0,1]$. It can't have a zero there. And it increases from $-2$ to $+\infty$ on $[1,+\infty)$. The zero(s) must be in that interval. If there were more than one zero (counting multiplicity) then, by Rolle's theorem the derivative would vanish at some point of $(-1,+\infty)$ but $\ln(x)>0$ in that interval. Therefore there is only one root.

Comment: Okay but how to solve xln(x)-x-1=0?

Comment: @user448075 there is no formula. It's not possible to find an exact solution. You need approximate solutions. Here we have $x\approx 3.59112$ here is one of the most effective methods https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method